# What is the origin of pharmacists being called 'yakuzaishi' in japanese? Is there some relation to the yakuza?

Tags: meaning, translation, etymology

I was doing a quick google translate search to look for the Japanese word for pharmacist. Turns out it is yakuzaishi. Ishi means doctor & Yakuza is obviously the well-known criminal syndicate. It beats me as to how this combination of words came to be regarded as the word for pharmacists in Japanese! Does it stand for a criminal doctor / useless doctor!!?

Comment: It Is yakuzai-shi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So yakuzai means drugs. Still, is there any connection with the yakuza? What is the etymology of this word?

Comment: 「ヤクザ医師」ってのは確かにちょっと面白いですが

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no connection between the words. The phonetic sharing of 'ya', 'ku' and 'za' is just a coincidence.

The word ヤクザ is thought to have derived from the scoring system of gambling games ([see this explanation](http://gogen-allguide.com/ya/yakuza.html#:%7E:text=%E3%80%90%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B6%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%9E%E6%BA%90%E3%83%BB%E7%94%B1%E6%9D%A5%E3%80%91,%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E5%A7%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82)), with the numbers 8, 9, 3 (= ya, ku, za) being an unwanted or useless combination. This is thought to be the origin of the name of the criminal gangs which became known as yakuza.

The word 薬剤師 (やくざい+し) is composed of the base word 薬剤 (medicine) and a suffix 師 (teacher, specialist). So the word simply means 'a specialist in medicines', which we now call 'pharmacist'. It is completely unrelated to the word ヤクザ.

In Japanese, there are many cases where there is a coincidental sharing of sounds which have no actual etymological connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, and dispelling my misconception!